# Why can't static properties use self explicitly in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, static, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind this simple concept.

In the code,

```
struct myStruct{

static let myWord = "Hello"
static let myWord2 = "World"

static let phrase = myWord + " " + myWord2

}
```

I understand the `phrase` assignment works, because statics are lazy and will wait until the instance exists.

What I want to understand is: if `self.myWord` will not work because `self` doesn't exist yet - how does the compiler obtain the value of `myWord` without referring to `self`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: static means it's globaly declared and that one instance for the class and not one instance per object so `self` is not relevant. You access them by doing `myStruct.phrase` for instance

Comment: The struct in this case is `Self` which represents the type. `self` represents the instance. `static let phrase = Self.myWord + " " + Self.myWord2`